# HTML Email Not Stacking in Outlook for iOS

Tags: outlook, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email, email-client

*I consider myself a beginner at email coding*

I am trying to get my email to stack on mobile in **Outlook for iOS** using CSS and @media queries. I've had success in other email clients but cannot figure out why it won't work in Outlook for iOS.

This is what I've already tried after reading through multiple bug reports and solutions on various websites:

- Changing the stacking `<td>` to `<th>`, didn't work
- Using only one @media query max-width size, didn't work
- Checked formatting of @media query to add appropriate spaces, didn't work
- Made sure the closing } } was separated by a space or line break between the two brackets, didn't work

Can anyone think of something else to try? The CSS classes that I use regularly are container, photo, drop. The drop class is what I'm trying to get to work here, as it works in other email clients fine. Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<style type="text/css">
    ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
    body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
} 
    p { margin: 1em 0; }
    table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #4D4E50;
}
    img { outline:0; }
    a img { border:none; }
    p { margin: 1em 0; }
    @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body .container { width:100% !important; }
    body .footer { width:auto !important; margin-left:0; }
    body .mobile-hidden, body .sideblock-hidden { display:none !important; }
    body .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
    body .photo img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }
    body .drop { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; }
    body .nav4, body .nav5, body .nav6 { display: none !important; }
    body .footerlogo { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; padding-top:15px; float:left; clear:both; }
    }
        </style>
<title>ENR InfoCenter</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" style="color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ececec">
<tr><td style="font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#000000;"><p align="center"><a href="@{mv_online_version}@" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">View this email in your web browser</a></p></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="container">
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">


<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="15">
<div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div>
</td>
<td class="photo"><img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/ENR/IC-Sensera-0923-redo/images/header.jpg" width="620" height="150" alt="ENR InfoCenter"/></td>
<td width="15"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>



</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="15">
<div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">

<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td>

<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 20px; line-height:24px; font-family: 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Times', serif; color:#393939;"><em>Technology Use in Construction</em></td></tr>
<tr><td><hr size="1" color="#cccccc" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="180" class="drop" valign="top"><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank"><img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/ENR/IC-Sensera-0923-redo/images/1.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="Photo of construction workers take a break"/></a></td>
<td width="15" class="drop"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td>
<td class="drop" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; line-height:20px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#545454;">
<span style="font-size: 22px; line-height:26px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#336899;"><strong>The Benefits of the Construction Equipment Rental Model</strong></span><br />
<em><strong>Construction companies are saving time and money by renting equipment, like forklifts and site cameras, more often.</strong></em><br /><br />

In 2022, <a href="https://www.statista.com/statistics/1224817/reasons-contractors-rented-construction-equipment-us/" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">62%</a> of contractors rented construction equipment because it provided more flexibility than owning. Specifically, contractors liked that they could return the equipment whenever they wanted with less overhead.<br /><br />

While buying construction equipment can sometimes be more practical than renting, it's not always the best option. In fact, industry experts say that if contractors use a piece of equipment <a href="https://www.constructionbusinessowner.com/equipment/deciding-whether-buy-construction-equipment-or-rent#:~:text=In%20the%20construction%20industry%2C%20a,purchasing%20or%20leasing%20the%20equipment." target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">less than 40% of the time</a>, it's smarter to rent it.<br /><br />

<strong><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">Continue Reading &rarr;</a></strong>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>

</table>
</td></tr>
</table>


</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="15"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>



<style type="text/css">
    ReadMsgBody{ width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass { width: 100%; }
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div { line-height: 100%; }
    body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
} 
    p { margin: 1em 0; }
    table td {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: #4D4E50;
}
    img { outline:0; }
    a img { border:none; }
    p { margin: 1em 0; }
    @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body .container { width:100% !important; }
    body .footer { width:auto !important; margin-left:0; }
    body .mobile-hidden, body .sideblock-hidden { display:none !important; }
    body .logo { display:block !important; padding:0 !important; }
    body .photo img { width:100% !important; height:auto !important; }
    body .drop { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; }
    body .nav4, body .nav5, body .nav6 { display: none !important; }
    body .footerlogo { display:block !important; width: 100% !important; padding-top:15px; float:left; clear:both; }
    }
        </style>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" style="color: #000000; margin: 0px; padding:0px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;">
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ececec">
<tr><td style="font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#000000;"><p align="center"><a href="@{mv_online_version}@" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">View this email in your web browser</a></p></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="container">
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">


<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="15">
<div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div>
</td>
<td class="photo"><img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/ENR/IC-Sensera-0923-redo/images/header.jpg" width="620" height="150" alt="ENR InfoCenter"/></td>
<td width="15"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>



</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="15">
<div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div>
</td>
<td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td style="padding-top:20px; padding-bottom:20px;">

<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td>

<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr>
<td style="font-size: 20px; line-height:24px; font-family: 'Georgia', 'Times New Roman', 'Times', serif; color:#393939;"><em>Technology Use in Construction</em></td></tr>
<tr><td><hr size="1" color="#cccccc" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tr><td width="180" class="drop" valign="top"><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank"><img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/ENR/IC-Sensera-0923-redo/images/1.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="Photo of construction workers take a break"/></a></td>
<td width="15" class="drop"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td>
<td class="drop" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; line-height:20px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#545454;">
<span style="font-size: 22px; line-height:26px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#336899;"><strong>The Benefits of the Construction Equipment Rental Model</strong></span><br />
<em><strong>Construction companies are saving time and money by renting equipment, like forklifts and site cameras, more often.</strong></em><br /><br />

In 2022, <a href="https://www.statista.com/statistics/1224817/reasons-contractors-rented-construction-equipment-us/" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">62%</a> of contractors rented construction equipment because it provided more flexibility than owning. Specifically, contractors liked that they could return the equipment whenever they wanted with less overhead.<br /><br />

While buying construction equipment can sometimes be more practical than renting, it's not always the best option. In fact, industry experts say that if contractors use a piece of equipment <a href="https://www.constructionbusinessowner.com/equipment/deciding-whether-buy-construction-equipment-or-rent#:~:text=In%20the%20construction%20industry%2C%20a,purchasing%20or%20leasing%20the%20equipment." target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">less than 40% of the time</a>, it's smarter to rent it.<br /><br />

<strong><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">Continue Reading &rarr;</a></strong>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>

</table>
</td></tr>
</table>


</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
<td width="15"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px">
<img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" />
</div></td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By collapse do you mean stack? If yes then you will need to target the `th` to do it. If you can add a small reproducible code (styles plus tables), then we can help in figuring out what's causing the issue.

Comment: you can add running code snippet as in example to enable better visualization of your question and expectation. Yout can refer the below example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77491028/close-modal-if-clicked-outside-of-modal-but-not-if-you-click-on-the-prev-or-next

Comment: @Syfer thanks for your reply. Yes, stack is a better word for it, thanks.  I added in more code above (a shortened version of the email, and also added as a running code snippet if that's better. Right now I have targeted the outer table with a container class, the table cell containing the large photo is targeted with the photo class, and the stacking table cells below are all targeted with the drop class. I did try replacing the `td` with `th` and target those instead but it didn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @KeerthanaPrabhakaran thanks for replying. I've added in the running code snippet, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided didn't have any `th` so here is a working example of the functionality you are after using your table but with minimal code.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .columns th{
      display:block !important;
      width:100%!important;
    }
  }
```

```html
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="columns">
        <tr>
          <th width="180" class="drop" valign="top" style="font-weight:normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;"><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank"><img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/ENR/IC-Sensera-0923-redo/images/1.jpg" width="180" height="180" alt="Photo of construction workers take a break"/></a></th>
          <th width="15" class="drop" style="font-weight:normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:left;"><div style="font-size:0pt; line-height:0pt; height:10px"> <img src="https://eblast.bnpmedia.com/Templates/files/empty.gif" width="10" height="10" style="height:10px" alt="" /> </div></th>
          <th class="drop" valign="top" style="font-size: 14px; line-height:20px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#545454;font-weight:normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:left;"><span style="font-size: 22px; line-height:26px; font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif; color:#336899;"><strong>The Benefits of the Construction Equipment Rental Model</strong></span><br />
            <em><strong>Construction companies are saving time and money by renting equipment, like forklifts and site cameras, more often.</strong></em><br />
            <br />
            In 2022, <a href="https://www.statista.com/statistics/1224817/reasons-contractors-rented-construction-equipment-us/" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">62%</a> of contractors rented construction equipment because it provided more flexibility than owning. Specifically, contractors liked that they could return the equipment whenever they wanted with less overhead.<br />
            <br />
            While buying construction equipment can sometimes be more practical than renting, it's not always the best option. In fact, industry experts say that if contractors use a piece of equipment <a href="https://www.constructionbusinessowner.com/equipment/deciding-whether-buy-construction-equipment-or-rent#:~:text=In%20the%20construction%20industry%2C%20a,purchasing%20or%20leasing%20the%20equipment." target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">less than 40% of the time</a>, it's smarter to rent it.<br />
            <br />
            <strong><a href="https://www.enr.com/articles/56953-the-benefits-of-the-construction-equipment-rental-model" target="_blank" style="color:#d92027">Continue Reading &rarr;</a></strong></th>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Additions done to your code:

- Class added to your table
- Media query added
- `td` changed to `th` for the table
- Style added `font-weight:normal;padding:0px;margin:0px;text-align:left;` to each `th`. This is done because `th` by default has a bolder font weight and text is always centred. Margin and Padding is just added to be safe if email clients have their own code being added

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem. I appreciate your help!