# Close modal if clicked outside of modal but not if you click on the prev or next links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like the modal box to close if you click outside of .modal but not if you click on the prev or next links, I am having trouble with that last part. I am not sure how to prevent the modal from closing if the prev or next links are clicked. The next buttons will be scrolling through different boxes so I need them clickable. Any help is appreciated.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', setup);

const get = document.getElementById.bind(document);
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function setup() {
  
  let modalRoot = get('modal-root');
  let button = get('modal-opener');
  let modal = query('.modal');
  
  modalRoot.addEventListener('click', rootClick);
  button.addEventListener('click', openModal);
  modal.addEventListener('click', modalClick);
  
  function rootClick() {
    modalRoot.classList.remove('visible');
  }
  
  function openModal() {
    modalRoot.classList.add('visible');
  }
  
  function modalClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
#modal-root {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left : 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height : 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out, width 0s linear 0.15s, height 0s linear 0.15s;
}

#modal-root.visible {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
}

.modal {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.prevslide, .nextslide{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.nextslide {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <button id="modal-opener">Open Modal</button>
</div>
<div id="modal-root">
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    <p>Modal contentt</p>
  </div>
<a class="prevslide" >Previous</a><a class="nextslide">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the both buttons and change your `rootClick()` function to check if the clicked target isn't one of the both buttons,

Check the snippet

```js
window.addEventListener('load', setup);

const get = document.getElementById.bind(document);
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function setup() {
  
  let modalRoot = get('modal-root');
  let button = get('modal-opener');
  let modal = query('.modal');
  // Define the both buttons
  let prev = query('.prevslide')
  let next = query('.nextslide')
  
  modalRoot.addEventListener('click', rootClick);
  button.addEventListener('click', openModal);
  modal.addEventListener('click', modalClick);
  
  function rootClick(e) {
  // Create if statement to check the target
  if(e.target != prev && e.target != next)
    modalRoot.classList.remove('visible');
  }
  
  function openModal() {
    modalRoot.classList.add('visible');
  }
  
  function modalClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
#modal-root {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left : 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height : 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out, width 0s linear 0.15s, height 0s linear 0.15s;
}

#modal-root.visible {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
}

.modal {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.prevslide, .nextslide{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.nextslide {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <button id="modal-opener">Open Modal</button>
</div>
<div id="modal-root">
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    <p>Modal contentt</p>
  </div>
<a class="prevslide" >Previous</a><a class="nextslide">Next</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could stop the event propagation when the prev/next buttons are clicked.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', setup);

const get = document.getElementById.bind(document);
const query = document.querySelector.bind(document);

function setup() {
  
  let modalRoot = get('modal-root');
  let button = get('modal-opener');
  let modal = query('.modal');
  
  modalRoot.addEventListener('click', rootClick);
  button.addEventListener('click', openModal);
  modal.addEventListener('click', modalClick);

  let prevBtn = modalRoot.querySelector(".prevslide");
  let nextBtn = modalRoot.querySelector(".nextslide");
  prevBtn.addEventListener("click", e => e.stopPropagation());
  nextBtn.addEventListener("click", e => e.stopPropagation());
  
  function rootClick() {
    modalRoot.classList.remove('visible');
  }
  
  function openModal() {
    modalRoot.classList.add('visible');
  }
  
  function modalClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

```css
#modal-root {
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left : 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0px;
  height : 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out, width 0s linear 0.15s, height 0s linear 0.15s;
}

#modal-root.visible {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
}

.modal {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.prevslide, .nextslide{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    color: red;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .6s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.nextslide {
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <button id="modal-opener">Open Modal</button>
</div>
<div id="modal-root">
  <div class="modal">
    <h3>Modal Header</h3>
    <p>Modal contentt</p>
  </div>
<a class="prevslide" >Previous</a><a class="nextslide">Next</a>
</div>
```